# Typescript - use for-loop for Obj in Array

Tags: angular, typescript

let's say i've got an Array like this:

```
let bodyDataAnswer = {
  'answers':[{
    'question_id':this.verifyCustomer.questions[0].id,
    'int_result':this.verifyCustomer.questions[0].answer_template.answers["0"].int_result,
    'string_result': this.verifyCustomer.questions[0].answer_template.answers["0"].string_result
    },
    {
      'question_id':this.verifyCustomer.questions[1].id,
      'int_result':this.verifyCustomer.questions[1].answer_template.answers["0"].int_result,
      'string_result': this.verifyCustomer.questions[1].answer_template.answers["0"].string_result,
    },
    {
      'question_id':this.verifyCustomer.questions[2].id,
      'int_result': this.verifyCustomer.questions[2].answer_template.answers["0"].int_result,
      'string_result':this.verifyCustomer.questions[2].answer_template.answers["0"].string_result
    }
    ]
  }
```

is there any way that i can use a for-loop for this? Because this gonna be bigger for the next time

Comment: You should really research the core basics of JavaScript before asking a question on SO… Just google "javascript for-loop", and you'll find at least four different ways to iterate data stored in arrays.

Comment: thanks, sorry i'm bad at this, i will improve it later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const bodyDataAnswer = {
    answers: this.verifyCustomer.questions.map(q => ({
        question_id: q.id,
        int_result: q.answer_template.answers["0"].int_result,
        string_result: q.answer_template.answers["0"].string_result
    }))
};
```